# Why do I have to enter the degrees twice in the loop?

Tags: c#, loops

Why do I have to enter the degrees twice when the loop starts? For example: the first time I enter 140 nothing happens, when I enter 140 again it continues the loop.

```
namespace Uppgift_2___Bastun
{
    class Program
    {
        static int FahrenheitToCelsius(int fahrenheit)
        {
            int celsius = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
            return celsius;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int celsius;

            Console.WriteLine("Hello! Welcome to the sauna!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your desired degrees in Fahrenheit: ");
            do
            {
                int fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                celsius = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
                Console.WriteLine("The sauna is now set to " + fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit, which equals to " + celsius + " degrees Celsius.");

                if (celsius < 25)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Way too cold! Turn the heat up: ");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (celsius < 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Too cold, turn the heat up: ");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (celsius < 73)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Just a little bit too cold, turn the heat up a little to reach the optimal temperature: ");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (celsius == 75)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The optimal temperature has been reached!");
                }
                else if (celsius > 77)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Too hot! Turn the heat down: ");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("The sauna is ready!");
                {
                }
            } while (celsius < 73 || 77 < celsius);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In *what* loop?

Comment: Forgot to paste it, edited now!

Comment: Jamie R Rytlewski answered your original question.  Please do not change the question and invalidate the answer.  If you have a new question that needs to be asked please open a new one.  Additionally, anything you can do to remove code and highlight just the area you're having trouble with will help a great deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues is that after you read the line in each of the if statements you don't do anything with it. It just repeats and does the readline here again:

```
int fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

So after the first loop you are doing ReadLine() twice.

Remove the ReadLine from in the if/else statements and it will work.

Comment: I'm also trying to add a Try/Catch to "int fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());" but can't get it to work, not really sure where to put it to make it work.